# DOMPDF Failed to load PDF document on server (production)

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using laravel 8 and have installed dompdf on MAMP and everything works fine, but as soon i deployed it to my production server dompdf does not work anymore.

I get the following message: Failed to load PDF document.

When I check the server logs i only a see 500 error without any additional details.

Is there anyone who has had the same issue?

I am using Laravel 8.12 with php 7.3.27 with dompdf

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
```

This is the code I use:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.letters', ['batch' => $batch]);
return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

I have checked and made sure:

- MBString extension is enabled
- DOM extension

I don't load in any custom fonts.

What I have tried:

- Downgrading from dompdf 0.9.0 to 0.8.0
- List item

Apache log returns no additional information only a 500 error.
Laravel log returns the following:

stdout: ""
command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy6039f3cdd6edf5.34383100.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy6039f3cdd702b5.29005326.pdf'. at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php:381)

This my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.8",
    "carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf": "^2.1",
    "darryldecode/cart": "^4.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "gladcodes/keygen": "^1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
    "mollie/laravel-mollie": "^2.0",
    "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^2.1",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.0.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.74"
},
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to install wkhtmltopdf on your server, see https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html or go to its github repo, clone it & then build it on server